# Cleaning up WindowsSDK Install Files via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm doing a powershell install of WindowsSDK and it leaves a ton of EULA files and other files in my C:\ directory.  I tried to find how to clear any temp files in C:\ but the only temp files that are deleted are in the actual %temp% directory.  And I'm not hardcoding the names of files to delete.

Comment: Since the people that write the software don't consider those to be temp files, there is nothing done by the system to identify them as such. So you will have to determine a way to identify them. Either by having a list or using some sort of name matching criteria.

Comment: hmm ok.  It's not the biggest deal, just unsightly... I can't even force install to put them in a folder somewhere?

Comment: Not unless the install is written to allow that. For what it is worth, I repackage software for a living and I have never seen an install that would allow this. They are not seen as special files, they are simply part of the install.

Comment: With all the other options on the windows packages I thought for sure there'd be a way to either delete those files after installation, or at least have them sit in their own directory somewhere not in C:\.  I mean come on... there's a bmp in there... who has ever been thankful that WindowsSDK put a bmp in their C:\ directory... Oh well.